# JMeter is not sending the Payload request 2nd time in the same flow

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter I am using an Application with Responsive UI for testing, where i need to pass a payload request and after that onwards Rest API request will be there. For doing re-login i need to pass the Payload request 2nd time in the same flow. But in JMeter on passing the payload request 2nd time, it does not send the request and skips it some how. How to resolve this.[image][image][image]

Comment: Did you see any errors during execution?

Comment: No i do not see any error..but it says user is locked

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
In the HTTP Cache Manager 'Use cache-control ...' check box was checked. On un-checking that, it started working properly.